# Why doesn't Java Sound Clip send LineListener events after pause and resume?

Tags: kotlin, audio-player, javax.sound.sampled

I have a simple audio test program in Kotlin that uses `Clip`:

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Getting clip...")
    val clip = AudioSystem.getClip()

    println("Opening clip...")
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File("/path/to/my/audio/file.wav")))

    println("Adding line listener...")
    clip.addLineListener {
            println("[ line listener ] $it")
    }

    println("Starting clip...")
    clip.start()
    Thread.sleep(500)

    println("Stopping clip...")
    clip.stop()
    Thread.sleep(1000)

    println("Restarting clip...")
    clip.start()

    // wait forever so we can see any more line listener events
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    latch.await()
}
```

My audio file is 1.1 seconds long. I would expected this program to play the first 0.5 second of the file, pause for 1 second, then finishing playing the file. When the playback starts, I expect to receive a `START` LineListener event, and when the playback stops/pauses I expect to receive a `STOP` LineListener event. I also expect to receive another `START` event when I unpause the the clip, and a final `STOP` event when the end of the file is reached. However, my output looks like:

```
Getting clip...
Opening clip...
Adding line listener...
Starting clip...
[ line listener ] Start event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@6afa9656
Stopping clip...
[ line listener ] Stop event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@6afa9656
Restarting clip...
```

I can hear the audio file stop, pause, and finishing playing as I expect, but I am not receiving any LineListener events after restarting the clip. If I do not pause and restart the clip, I correctly receive the end-of-file `STOP` event.

Why am I not seeing any LineListener events after resuming the Clip?

**EDIT:**

If I add this line

```
clip.framePosition = clip.framePosition
```

immediately following `clip.stop()` and before `Thread.sleep(1000)`, the problem disappears and the LineListener receives the expected events:

```
Getting clip...
Opening clip...
Adding line listener...
Starting clip...
[ line listener ] Start event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@3ddc3924
Stopping clip...
[ line listener ] Stop event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@3ddc3924
Restarting clip...
[ line listener ] Start event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@3ddc3924
[ line listener ] Stop event from line com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip@3ddc3924
```

**Is this a bug in the Clip implementation?**